# Autohotkey mouse becomes inactive

Tags: autohotkey

just starting with AHK and looking to automate some PC performance monitoring with GPU-Z and Resource Monitor. I'm trying to write a simple script that starts the data logging process for each of these programs. I haven't completed the script yet, as I cannot get the mouse to do anything once I've activated the GPU-Z window. There is probably something pretty simple I'm missing, but I cannot work it out.

```
#NoEnv
#Warn
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

^F2::

If WinExist("ahk_class #32770")
{
    MouseMove 490, 90, 100 ;Mouse moves all ok first time script is run
    WinActivate
    ControlClick Button17 ;Click the "Log to file" button --> doesn't work
}
Else
{
    ;Blank for now
}

If WinExist("ahk_class MMCMainFrame")
{
    MouseMove 100, 100, 100, R ;Mouse does not move at all
    WinActivate
}
Else
{
    ;Blank for now
}

return
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a permissions / security issue. Running the script as Administrator solved it.